# Finding C(x,y) equidistant from multiple points

Tags: graphing-functions

1. Given that C(x, y) is equidistant from each of the points P(1, 5), Q (−5, −3) and R(2, −2), use the distance formula to form two equations in x and y and solve them simultaneously to find the coordinates of C.

I tried to solve the above question but I got (-9,0) which is wrong since the answer is (-2,1)

2. Given the point A(7, 8), find the coordinates of three points P with integer coordinates such that AP = √5.

I don't understand what to do with this one either. Please send your working out so I can see where I went wrong!

Comment: Instead of asking for someone to feed you a solution, it would be better to show your work that led to the incorrect answer. You might’ve been on the right track and just made some silly algebraic error along the way, and if you show what work someone will be able to point out your mistake.

Comment: @amd I did it on a whiteboard so I do not have track of my working out so I am SO sorry about that. I'm not asking anyone to feed me a solution, it's their choice to do that - I'm just asking for any form guidance or assistance preferably in the form of some working out as aforementioned. Plus, for the second question, I don't even know where to start so how am I going to send my working out?

Comment: For the second question, you’re being asked to find points with integer coordinates on a circle centered at $A$. Can you think of two integers whose squares add up to $5$?

Comment: @amd 2 and 1 but I'm still confused what it's asking to be honest aha

Comment: I’ve already told you exactly what it is that the problem is asking you to do.